# Upper Darboux Sum and Integration

Tags: integration, continuity

Suppose that $f$ is monotone increasing on $[a, b]$ and that $\pi_{k}$ denotes the unfom partition of $[a, b]$ with gauge $\frac{(b-a)}{k}$. Prove that
$$
0 \leq U\left(f, \pi_{k}\right)-\int_{a}^{b} f(x) d x \leq[f(b)-f(a)] \frac{b-a}{k}
$$

The LHS inequality seems to be intuitively correct although mathematical rigor is missing. Regarding the RHS part, I could not come up with any solid ideas or alternative approaches for progressive results. What would you suggest to proceed with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

We know that

$$L(f,\pi_k)\le \int_a^bf\le U(f,\pi_k)$$
with $ f $ increasing ,

$$L(f,\pi_k)=\frac{b-a}{k}\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}f(x_i)$$
and

$$U(f,\pi_k)=\frac{b-a}{k}\sum_{i=1}^kf(x_i)$$

thus

$$0\le U(f,\pi_k)-\int_a^bf\le$$
$$ U(f,\pi_k)-L(f,\pi_k)=$$
$$\frac{b-a}{k}(f(x_k)-f(x_0))=$$
$$\frac{b-a}{k}(f(b)-f(a))$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the initial formulas of how one can prove them? Referring to the lower/upper Darboux sum formulas, how we could prove it with mathematical rigor?!

Comment: Moreover, is it necessary to derive the fact that integral lies between upper and lower Darboux sum? It is pretty intuitive, but I would be rather glad if solely mathematical rigor could prove such a beautiful property.

Comment: @Snowflake It follows from the fact that $\int_a^bf=\sup L(f,P)=\inf U(f,P)$